# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' error for docker run

Tags: python, docker, powershell

I have created the docker image to run python script. Now when I run below command it throwing error.
command in powershell:
**docker build -t pull_request_summary .**

**Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/app/src/./listPullRequest.py", line 1, in 
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'**

Just to confirm the "requests module is already installed on my machine. The script is running fine if I directly run from PowerShell. It just throwing error while running docker images.
My question is where it is expecting the "request" module of python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your container also must have requests installed on it
In your docker file put this line

```
RUN pip install requests
```

Comment: Thanks @Hamed Maaleki. It helped me to resolve issue. I further added few more library install lines .

Comment: I have this issue but already have `RUN pip install requests` in the Dockerfile, any other reason/fix for python not being able to find requests?  I also see this during build: `WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions`

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error even when including `RUN pip install requests` in the Dockerfile. My solution was to change from:

```
CMD ./myscript.py
```

to:

```
CMD [ "python", "./myscript.py" ]
```

Comment: What is the first line of your script?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python3

Comment: try 
#!/usr/bin/env python3
it should works